# multiprocessing.pool on windows/jupyter

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, python-multiprocessing

This is a problem I've had only within jupyter notebook, not with running through python3 normally (even though using the same conda environment).

If I run the following code on my windows machine via jupyter notebook:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x


pool = Pool(4)
for res in pool.map(f,range(10)):
    print(res)
```

I do not see any values returned. I see the multiple python processes get spawned but there is 0 cpu load on them and nothing is returned.

If I run this as a python script (within the same conda environment) I get the proper response.

Is there a way to use multiprocessing.pool in jupyter/windows?

Thank you!